# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '< with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just hosting hello world with react and get the message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '< with react
```

my code looks like this:

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="root">
         <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
      </div>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script>
         console.log("test")
         
         ReactDOM
         .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
         .render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <h1>Hello, world!</h1> is JSX code. This is not understandable by the navigators. You must have a tool like webpack or other to compile the react code.

Answer (score 1):

`<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` is jsx. You need babel to convert it to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So, i added:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">...
```

to make it work. I needed to understand, that i could use react without jsx or vs versa.

I also found this video, which explains the concepts of react very well imho:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAIdyBFHfVU